# File selection window opens behind R main window

Tags: r, shiny, tcltk

I saw this question has been asked before but not answered. When using `tcltk::tk_choose.files()` the first time during an R session it opens behind the R main window. All further times it opens in front of the main window (as it should!). Is there a way to have it always in the very front?
Ultimately I would like to use it via shiny as below. So it should also be in front of the shiny window.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("do", "Open window")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$do, {
        tcltk::tk_choose.files()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am aware of `base::file.choose()` and `utils::choose.files()`. However, the first does not allow to select multiple files at once and the second does not allow to copy/paste paths for quicker navigation which drives me crazy,..

Comment: Have you tried with `base::file.choose()` and/or `utils::choose.files()`?

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of those but would like to avoid them. I updated my question to explain why

Comment: I'm using Windows and it works fine from the R session. When using from shiny, it fails. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Also, it crashes my RStudio session.

Comment: Oh ok. I realized by now that on some computers (all windows7) it seems to always open in the front, on others it is as described above. However, for me it never crashed